# How to implement UISearchBar with no border

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uisearchbar

I am trying to add a UISearchBar without the border around it, but it's simply not working.

This is what I have:

On the XIB file, I added UISearchBar. Style = Black Transparent. Tint = Default. None of the options (bookmarks, cancel button, scope bar, etc) are selected. Background = Default. Drawing = opaque (basically the default setting of the UISearchBar).

I have a property for UISearchBar - searchBar.
In the implementation file, when the view loads, I have:

```
[[self.searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
```

But for whatever reason, the background (the dark border around the box) is simply not going.
I tried [[self.searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setAlpha:0], but that's not working at all either.

Any help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the code .....

```
for (id img in searchBar.subviews)
{       
     if ([img isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")])
     {     
            [img removeFromSuperview];    
     }
}
```

happy coding :)

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me

```
for (UIView * view in [[[self.searchBar subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews])
{
    if (![view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
    {
        view .alpha = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
[self.searchBar setOpaque:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[[_searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
_searchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Hope this work for you, its working for me.

Comment: Did not work for me. The searchbar isn't shown at all and the view is not correctly responding to taps. Using iOS 8.

Answer (score 1):

this work only in static UISearchBar, not if you want to show search CancelButton, this problem occur in devices having ios above 5.0. 
For that you have to change/set BackgroundView of UiSearchBar.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
 for (UIView * view in [mySearchBar subviews]) {
     if (![view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
    view .alpha = 0;
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

For those of you using 8.0 and above, the best solution is to simply use the `UIAppearance` protocol, by doing the following:

```
[[UISearchBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarPosition:UIBarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

You can also do it on one specific instance with:

```
[mySearchBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarPosition:UIBarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 0):

if someone has same problem as I (see picture) code above could fix

```
[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-1, 0, 0, 0)];
```